# How to complete regex statement to validate initials

Tags: javascript, regex

I am expected to use regex only to validate initials. The initials have to follow the following format:

1. Initials have to be capital letters only
2. Each letter has to be followed by a period
3. Each *Letter-Period* pair can only be separated by 1 space
4. Luckily leading and trailing whitespaces are okay

I was able to capture capital letter-period pair but I have trouble stopping it from accepting lowercase letters and having exactly one whitespace in between.

```
var pattern = /[A-Z\s]+(.)/gi;
```

I expect that when tested against a string like "`H. P.`" that it would return `true`. When tested against strings like "`H. p.`", "`H. P`" that it would return `false`.

Comment: The most immediate issue you mentioned (keep it from accepting lowercase) is because you have an `i` flag on your pattern which makes it case-insensitive

Comment: _"Each Letter-Period pair **can** only be separated by one space"_  is the space optional or required?

Comment: You'll need to escape the dot, too (use `\.` instead of `.`) because `.` means matching *anything*, while `\.` means match a literal dot.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your requirements and work out what patterns match each part. In no particular order...

1. *Leading and trailing whitespaces are okay*

   This one's easy, just add `\s*` to the start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors

   ```js
   /^\s*...\s*$/
   ```
2. *Initials have to capital letters only*

   A character class with upper-case letters satisfies this

   ```js
   /[A-Z]/
   ```
3. *Each letter has to be followed by a period*

   Add a literal period to the previous pattern

   ```js
   /[A-Z]\./
   ```

To join all this together, I'm going to make the following assumptions...

1. There must be at least one initial (upper-case letter and period)
2. Initials **must** be separated by a single space character

This results in the following pattern

```js
/^\s*[A-Z]\.( [A-Z]\.)*\s*$/
```

Broken down, this is

```js
/
 ^\s*         # zero-or-more spaces at the start of the string
 [A-Z]\.      # upper-case letter followed by period
 ( [A-Z]\.)*  # zero-or-more repetitions of space + letter + period
 \s*$         # zero-or-more spaces at the end of the string
/
```

```js
const rx = /^\s*[A-Z]\.( [A-Z]\.)*\s*$/
const tests = [' H.  ', 'h', 'h.', 'H. P.', 'H.P.', 'H. p.', 'H. P. L.']

tests.forEach(str =>
    console.info(str, ' = ', rx.test(str)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression might simply work just OK:

```
^\s*[A-Z]\.\s[A-Z]\.\s*$
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/B69onM/1/)

or if you had more than two letters requirement, we would add a quantifier with upper and lower bounds:

```
^\s*[A-Z]\.(?:\s[A-Z]\.){1,2}\s*$
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/LOTdRJ/1/)

and we can continue limiting the number of spaces as well:

```
^\s{0,4}[A-Z]\.(?:\s[A-Z]\.){1,2}\s{0,3}$
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/hiN9ul/1/)

```js
const regex = /^\s*[A-Z]\.(?:\s[A-Z]\.){1,2}\s*$/gm;
const str = `H. P.
H. P.  
  H. P.  
  H. P. K.
  H. P. K. M. 
H. p.
H. P`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
 if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
  regex.lastIndex++;
 }

 m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
  console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
 });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Nice, wish I'd though of using the non-capturing group. What's the reasoning for limiting the repeating initials to 2?